# Converting this ARM64 Assembly into Python?

Tags: python, assembly, arm64

Assume X6 is the base address for array "A"

Assume X7 is the base address for array "B"

F,G,H,I = X0,X1,X2,X3,X4 respectively

What exactly is this AArch64 assembly doing?

A python code representation using the above variables would be amazing :)

```
ADD  X9,  X6, #8     // I understand this is X9 = A + 8, not sure what the value of the array would be here

ADD  X10, X7, #16    // Same idea

STUR X1, [X6, #0]    // I believe this "Stores" the value at X1 into A[0]?

LDUR X8,  [X10,#0]   // This "stores" the value at ?X10[0]? into X8?

LDUR X5,  [X9, #0]   // This "stores" the value at ?X9[0]? into X5?

ADD  X0,  X8, X5     // F = X8 + X5
```

I get lost during the LDUR stages and what exactly is in X5 and X8

Comment: You have 3 instructions here. Have you consulted an instruction set reference on what each does? Which part is unclear?

Comment: Hello Jester, Yes I used the ARM64 reference guide along with a written guide on the language. I have edited my question to include what I do (or at least I think) understand along with where I get lost. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

> ADD X9, X6, #8
>
> I understand this is X9 = A + 8, not sure what the value of the array would be here

Correct. The value of `X6` is just the base address of the array, as the problem description says.

> STUR X1, [X6, #0]
>
> I believe this "Stores" the value at X1 into A[0]?

Correct. `X1` has been defined as variable `G` in the problem description. So that's `A[0] = G;`

> LDUR X8, [X10,#0]
>
> This "stores" the value at ?X10[0]? into X8?

Correct, but moving data from memory into a register is called a load. Hence the instruction name (LD = load). Also remember that `X10` has been set to `X7+16` with `X7` being the array `B`. Furthermore, `LDUR` uses byte indexing so the 16 means 16 bytes. Assuming `B` is an array containing 64 bit numbers that's 8 bytes per item so 16 bytes is 2 items. All of this boils down to `X8 = B[2];`.

> LDUR X5, [X9, #0]

By the same logic, this is `X5 = A[1];` so the final result is `F = B[2] + A[1];`.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning that `ldur` is just a form of `ldr` that allows arbitrary byte offsets instead of only multiples of the operand-size.  IDK why the original used that when the addressing modes all use `#0` as the offset.  Maybe also simplify the asm to use addressing-mode offsets instead of separate `add` instructions.  Or not since I doubt many future readers will see this.